# Local installation - Can not read file from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I have been trying to read files from s3 bucket but getting an error. I have downloaded hadoop-aws-2.7.3 jar and aws-java-sdk 1.11.842 to local machines and made available these 4 jars files to local installations JAR directory.

Jars:

[image]

Error:

```
File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import file_config

spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("my_app") \
            .getOrCreate()

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "key")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "key")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "us-east-1.amazonaws.com")

csv_df = spark.read.format("csv").load("s3a://bucketname/list_file.txt")
csv_df.show()
```

Comment: what spark version and for what version of hadoop? is that same with your jars? 2.7.3?

Comment: I have this installation to local windows machine so win utility installed , not Hadoop, is there a way around ?